# Dictionary Value Reading and Assignment Performance

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary

The closest question I could find here is [C# Dictionary Loop Enhancment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408192/c-sharp-dictionary-loop-enhancment), but that didn't help me.

Following code is what I have in my project. The data structures are quite complex so just for the sake of explaining I have created simple form of them here:

```
public class BusinessObject
{
    public Dictionary <int, InnerObject> objList = new Dictionary <int, InnerObject>();
    public string Name {set;get;}

    public Dictionary <int, InnerObject> ObjectList // <index, InnerObject>
    {
        get
        {
            return ojbList;
        }
    }
}

...
...
...
// <Name of the BusinessObject, BusinessObject>
public Dictionary <string, BusinessObject> BusinessObjectList; 
// names of all the business objects has an index in this dictionary
public Dictionary <int, string> BusinessObjectListIndexes 

...
...
...

//On receiving the values over TCP, following loop executes. This loop will iterate over about a million values depending on the type of that value:

int currentIndex = 0;
string name = "";
InnerObject tempInnerObject;

for(int i = 0; i < valueCountReceivedOverTCP; i++) // valueCountReceivedOverTCP can be up to 1 million
{
/* 1. */ name = BusinessObjectListIndexes[i];                                     
/* 2. */ tempInnerObject = BusinessObjectList[name].ObjectList[i];                
/* 3. */ tempInnerObject.ReceivedTime = valuesReceivedOverTCP->Time;               

    switch(valuesReceivedOverTCP->Type)
    {
        case TCPType.INT:
            bytearray[0] = valuesReceivedOverTCP->Values[++currentIndex];
                        bytearray[1] = valuesReceivedOverTCP->Values[++currentIndex];
                        bytearray[2] = valuesReceivedOverTCP->Values[++currentIndex];
                        bytearray[3] = valuesReceivedOverTCP->Values[++currentIndex];

                        tempint = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytearray, 0);
 /* 4. */           tempInnerObject.Value = tempint;                      
        break;

        case TCPType.DOUBLE:                                                
                        bytearray[0] = valuesReceivedOverTCP->Values[currentIndex+1];
                        bytearray[1] = valuesReceivedOverTCP->Values[currentIndex+2];

                        bytearray[2] = valuesReceivedOverTCP->Values[currentIndex+3];
                        bytearray[3] = valuesReceivedOverTCP->Values[currentIndex+4];

                        bytearray[4] = valuesReceivedOverTCP->Values[currentIndex+5];
                        bytearray[5] = valuesReceivedOverTCP->Values[currentIndex+6];

                        bytearray[6] = valuesReceivedOverTCP->Values[currentIndex+7];
                        bytearray[7] = valuesReceivedOverTCP->Values[currentIndex+8];

                        currentIndex += 8;                        
                        tempdouble = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytearray, 0);
/* 5. */                tempInnerObject.Value = tempdouble; 


        break;
    }

}
```

Lines marked from 1 to 5 are the ones with issue. I found that the above lines are taking time using ANTS Performance Profiler. They all take considerable amount of time. Line No. 2 is the main time waster. The for loop takes about 250 milliseconds for about 700,000 values. Even though it's in milliseconds I want to reduce it because this is unacceptable in for the software. I have also tried splitting this for loop into 4 parallel loops using `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke()` but no success.

My question is - do you see anything obviously wrong with this logic or code? What can be the solution to get this code running faster. I understand that if I have hit the performance limitation of .NET Dictionary then I have to implement the whole thing differently. I am open any suggestion even if it means changing my design/implementation to get this code running faster.

**EDIT:**
As a very first TCP message I get the order and total count of these values. I save the order as a key and Business Object Name as value in `BusinessObjectListIndexes`. First message onwards I don't get the BusinessObject name. Only values are received in the same order as specified by the first message. I then update the BusinessObjectList with values received in every message. This is where I need performance improved. A TCP message is received every 250 milliseconds that gives updated values.

Comment: If memory isn't as much of a concern, you could try initialising the dictionaries with a larger capacity and see if there's a point which reduces the time http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-optimization

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the logic there... can your reorganize that stuff and use Dictionary <int, BusinessObject> instead of 2 dictionaries that you have right now? Then your lines 1 and 2 would merge into something like tempInnerObject = BusinessObjectList[i].ObjectList[i]; ... maybe there's another logical issue with i being used to index to 2 things, but that can also be an artifact of copy-pasting + editing

Comment: @Mike Trusov, I cannot merge those 2 dictionaries into a single one because - The data being received over TCP is based on index. So I need the index of business objects in the for loop mentioned above. Hence the Dictionary <int, string> is used to convert business object name to index. At all the other times the Business Object Dictionary is accessed by using its name.

Comment: I don't see any reason why BusinessObjectListIndexes should be a dictionary, it could be an array instead. Maybe ObjectList too. If I understand correctly, you are reciving the the values out of order, and you don't know how many beforehand... if so, you may need to write a wrapper that will automatically copy the array to a bigger one as more space is needed. If you are reciving them in order, just use a List<T>. If you know how many, use an array.

Comment: @Theraot, Do you think using Array will give me any performance improvement over the dictionary? Answer to your second point - I receive the values in order over TCP. My very first TCP message gives the information about the total no. of values and their order. Sorry that my original question doesn't explain this. I will edit it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @silverspoon Using an array gives a performance boost, in particular knowing the size beforehand. Why? because, the dictionary needs to hash, solve collisions and grow. The default implementation of Dictionary<TKey, TValue> uses separate chaining (duckduckgo that) meaning that if there is a collision it will take linear time among the items in the same bucket to find the key. Anyway, setting the capacity of the dictionary's constructor should prevent both growing and those collitions [when using contiguous ints as key, because the default hash of an int is the int itself].

Comment: Agree with @Theraot, you could use an array and try "manage memory" by yourself. The fact that .NET is a garbage collected environment doesn't mean that you cannot setup memory handling strategies. Give a look at Firefly Http Server (https://github.com/FireflyServer/firefly) and how it manages memory with MemoryPool class (http://goo.gl/fWUbe).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are only using the key in both the `BusinessObjectListIndexes` and `ObjectList` properties as an index. The `Dictionary` class doesn't know this though and still has to search for your key/index.

If you changed those to an `Array`, if you know the size before hand, or even a `List<int>`, if you don't know the size or just find it easier to use, I suspect you would get better performance. Depending on the (average?) size(s) you may find another type better suited still but the point being that a dictionary doesn't seem to be the right choice here.